# Why does Play port not get started with library subproject?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

In `build.sbt` I have the lines like:

```
lazy val sparkCommon = (project in file("spark-common"))//.enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
                  .dependsOn(sparkCommon).aggregate(sparkCommon)
```

In `spark-common` project I have code in `src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala`:

```
 object SimpleApp {
    def getStr = "{ name = 'adf'}"
 }
```

In my Spark project `root` I am trying to use that code.

With the `build.sbt` file above port listening is not started and I cannot access my service (but it compiles projects successfully, can make both packages and publish them to repo).

If I uncomment line `enablePlugins(PlayScala)` for my library `spark-common` project in the `build.sbt` file, it does not see `SimpleApp` (as I understand Play projects have a bit different structure, thus compilation error is reasonable, as code located under `/spark-common/src/main/scala/SimleApp.scala`).

It seems that I follow [guideline](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/2.3$20playscala$20/play-framework/lnEcyiPewn0/z49BVJD1Z60J)  (I use Play 2.3.4), but it does not work. What can be an issue?

activator run / sbt run command result:

```
[info] Done updating.

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/tkacheni/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/o
rg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/tkacheni/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1
.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Projects command results:

```
[rest-service] $ projects
[info] In file:/C:/Git/rest-service/
[info]   * root
[info]     sparkCommon
[rest-service] $
```

If I run last run I can see such an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        ...
```

I have found a similar issue in [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/2.3$20playscala$20/play-framework/lnEcyiPewn0/z49BVJD1Z60J), but it doesn't help me

Comment: Can you do `activator run` and include the output to the question? Can you also do `activator projects` and add the output, too?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski See result in the post

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Did you try http://localhost:9000? There are issues with the appenders so the port may've not just been printed out.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Yes, I did try it :). Moreover, if I remove multi project settings, it works perfectly. But I have only one project compiled - Play. I can say even more - as I mentioned, if I uncomment line //.enablePlugins(PlayScala) in build .sbt (and comment code in Play project which uses subprojects) it also compiles and runs linstening.